# Помощь с написанием регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, замена

Добрый день. Есть куча строк вида

> abc - Пункт 1 **And** Пункт 2 **And** Пункт 3 - cde - fgh

Необходимо заменить все And на & между "abc - " и " - cde". Другими словами, чтобы получилось

> abc - Пункт 1 **&** Пункт 2 **&** Пункт 3 - cde - fgh

В идеале, если это реализовать для Notepad++, а не на на ЯП

Заранее спасибо

---

Банальная замена не подходит. Это я абстрактно написал: вместо cde и/или fgh может быть целая строка, которая тоже может включать **And**, а там не должно заменяться. Ключевое условие - надо заменить And только между первыми дефисами. "Тупое решение в лоб" я так понял, ищет всю строку, подходящую данному шаблону, но не выделяет "энды".

Вот пример вживую:

> stackoverflow.com - **2017.12.26 - Java And PHP And C# And Perl And
>   HTML** - Языки программирования And разметки
>
> github.com - 2014.02.19 - **Мама And Мыла And Раму** - Пословицы и
>   поговорки And русского народа. Издание 2017 год

В итоге должно получиться:

> stackoverflow.com - 2017.12.26 - Java **&** PHP **&** C# **&** Perl **&** HTML - Языки
>   программирования And разметки
>
> github.com - 2014.02.19 - Мама **&** Мыла **&** Раму - Пословицы и поговорки
>   And русского народа. Издание 2017 год

То есть, замена должна производиться только в выделенном диапазоне

Comment: Простая замена одного на другое, я так полагаю, вам не подходит?

Comment: `Пункт Х`на практике то какие значения принимает? и может ли их быть больше трех за раз.

Comment: тупое решение влоб https://regex101.com/r/MNYYJ5/1